# accessing private class memers in ctor

Tags: c++, oop, templates, smart-pointers, private-members

I have the following members of a smart pointer class:

```
T *local_raw_ptr;
const memory_management_type local_type;
```

where `memory_management_type` is a enum.
To do an implicit cast to base classes i want to implement this ctor:

```
template<
            typename T2,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, T2>::value>::type
    >
    pointer(const pointer<T2>& ptr):local_type(ptr.local_type), local_raw_ptr(ptr.local_raw_ptr) {};
```

but if I try to compile this I get this error:

```
pointer<Foo>::local_raw_ptr« is private within this context
```

why I am not able to access the private members of this class in its own constuctor? And how can i solve this problem?

Comment: no it is in the header file

Comment: As a template ctor, the passed `pointer<T2>` will be an irrelevant class, its private members couldn't be accessed in current class.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Try giving an MCVE (a small but COMPLETE sample of code that exhibits the same problem).     At a guess through,  a member function of `pointer<X>` will not be able to access private members of  `pointer<Y>`, since `pointer<X>` and `pointer<Y>` are different (non-friend) classes, unless `X` and `Y` are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because every instantiation of a template class is a different class from the others.

So if you have `pointer<Foo>` and `pointer<Bar>` there are two different classes and `pointer<Foo>` private members are not accessible from `pointer<Bar>`.

You are trying to access `local_type` of `pointer<T2>` from `pointer<T>` constructor. The fact that `T2` is a subtype of `T` is irrelevant.